# Why cant I see some edges that are selected?

Tags: vertices, edges

[image]
[image]

It looks like I can see edges that are more highlighted, but I can't see those that aren't.

Comment: They may overlap with another not selected one.

Comment: How does it look if you copy and paste the model into a new blender file? (In Object mode select the model, Ctrl C to copy it, File > New > General > Ctrl V to paste into a new blender file.) and if necessary remove the existing material and create a new one for it.